# String concatenation with sprintf

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I always got in troubles when it comes to concatenation on C++, i have a float value im converting to a char array, then im trying to append some text in front of that value, but im getting a "?" as output, here's the code:

```
int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
float voltage= sensorValue * (5.0 / 421.0);
char v[6];
dtostrf(voltage, 6, 2, v);
sprintf(_outbuffer,  "VL%s", v);
Serial.println(v);
Serial.println(_outbuffer);
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to tag this as `C`?

Comment: Why are you bothering with this `dtostrf()` function? You should just be able to do `sprintf(_outbuffer,  "VL%6.2f", voltage);` (you might need to mess with that format specifier to get float displayed the way you want). Also consider using `snprintf()` so you don't overrun `_outbuffer`.

Comment: Decide actually, [tag:c] or [tag:c++]!! Downvoting for pressure, as it stands the question isn't suitable for [tag:c++] ... Any reasons you cannot use `std::string` or other c++ standard library classes as mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) is **easy**, just use the `+` operator :

```
std::string s1("Hello");
std::string s2("World");
std::string concat = s1 + s2; // concat will contain "HelloWorld"
```

If you need advanced formatting features or numeric formatting, you can use the `std::ostringstream` class:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << 1 << "," << 2 << "," << 3 << ", Hello World!";
std::string result = oss.str(); // result will contain "1,2,3, Hello World!"
```

So, for your situation, you can use this:

```
int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 421.0);
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::fixed << std::setw(6) << std::setprecision(2) << voltage;
std::string v = oss.str();
std::string _outbuffer = "VL" + v;
Serial.println(v.c_str());
Serial.println(_outbuffer.c_str());
```

**Note:**
To use iostream manipulator functions (as the mentioned `std::setw()`, etc.) you'll need to [`#include <iomanip>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) besides `#include <ostringstream>`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau THX, nice enhancement for the answer. I was just too lazy then, and hoping a > 2000 rep user is able to cope the interpolation ...

Comment: I don't pay attention to reps, and you never know who will see it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try strcat

```
char v[15 + 1];
v[15] = 0;
dtostrf(voltage, 6, 2, v);
strcpy(_outbuffer, "VL");
strcat(_outbuffer, v);
```

Alternatively, as suspectus suggested, use sprintf.